# Enterprise Library 5.0 - Validation - Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I am using the Validation Application Block (VAB) of the Enterprise Library 5.0.
All is working well and I get the appropriate messages, but when I navigate to another tab in the tab control and navigate back the validation messages have all disappeared and don't reappear until I change a value to be invalid again.

The application is a WPF application and I am using standard VAB libraries to integrate with the application.

How can I tell the UI to re-evaluate all validation and display the errors?

Comment: Which technology are we talking about? Forms, WPF, ASP.NET Web Forms, MVC, other? How did you integrate VAB with this technology? Through the VAB integration libraries or in another way? Please show more information about the context.

Comment: Question updated with clarification

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the Tab/Controls, check [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411297/equivalent-of-winforms-textbox-validating-event-in-wpf).